# Casting from a to b then b to a is identity?

Tags: coq

Given the definition:

```
Definition cast (a b:Type) (p:a = b) (x:a) : b :=
    match p with
    | eq_refl _  => x
    end.
```

I was hoping that the following lemma would be provable:

```
Lemma cast_cast_is_id : forall (a b:Type) (x:a) (p:a = b) (q:b = a),
    cast b a q (cast a b p x) = x.
```

However, I do not seem to be able to carry out a proof for this. I can destruct `p` successfully, but cannot destruct `q` after that. Replacing the lemma's statement with `eq_sym p` instead of arbitrary `q` does not help me either it seems.

I fear I have unwittingly stumbled into some subtle point of HoTT.

Can anyone prove this lemma or is it known to be unprovable without further axioms?

Comment: Replacing `q` by `eq_sym p` in the lemma statement does work. Just destruct `p` and you are done.

Comment: I believe is actually the *opposite* of HoTT! If you have this, you collapse every path `x = y` into single point and the topological structures of HoTT disintegrate into a collection of discrete points.

Comment: @GuillaumeMelquiond Yes I agree a less general result with ```eq_sym p``` is easily provable (not sure why I didn't see on first try). This is great thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not completely sure, but it seems to me that what you are trying to prove is no different from `forall a (p:a=a), p = eq_refl`. If so, you cannot prove it in Coq, unless you know something about `a`, e.g., decidable equality. In that case, you can use the results on UIP (unicity of identity proofs) from the [standard library](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Logic.Eqdep_dec.html).